# How to clear a validation error in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a simple registration page in my Django web application. Once a user signs up, I am able to query my database and see if the username is already in use, if it is, I display a simple `ValidationError`.

My problem is I can't figure out how to remove the error after a few seconds. I'm pretty good with Python but haven't found any luck, the only thing I can find is [this][1] outdated article from 2010 that gives me code that doesn't work anymore.

Bellow is my function for recognizing if the username is already in use and my HTML file. Thank you to everyone who helps!

```
def clean(self):
          cleaned_data=super().clean()
          if User.objects.filter(username=cleaned_data["username"]).exists():
            raise ValidationError("This username is taken, please try another one")
```

Comment: You need to do this on the client side using some JavaScript. Once the response with the error has been returned to the client you cannot modify it from the server

Comment: Do you have an example of how that would look like? I am not really good with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very basic script that will remove all errors on the page after 3 seconds. Add it to the bottom of your HTML so that it is run after everything has rendered

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function() {
    let errors = document.getElementsByClassName('errorlist');
    while(errors.length > 0) {
      errors[0].parentNode.removeChild(errors[0]);
    }
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Maybe it has something to do with my HTML. I am updating my question with my HTML document

Comment: Updated my question to include my HTML file

Comment: I'm not sure what class crispy forms adds to each error. Can you inspect the HTML and then use that class instead of errorlist

Comment: Updated the answer with a better (actually working) way of removing elements